# HTML page layout changed suddenly to show divisions smaller

Tags: html, debugging

I am creating a webpage and I had completed a basic layout which was working completely fine. All the divisons were of proper size. But suddenly, i pressed some button accidentally and now it has become skewed. It has actually become smaller scaled.

Can someone please help me find out what is the bug here? I am trying but I am not sure, how to debug this.

Thanks.

```
HTML File:

<html>

<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyle.css">
</head>
<body>

<div id="header">
<h1>ABCD</h1
</div>

<div id="subheader">
<h3>Certified General Accountant&nbsp</h3>
</div>

<div id="sidebar">
Hello
Hi
How
</div>

<div id="content">
Main Body!!
</div>

<div id="footer">
Contact Us
</div>

</body>
</html>

CSS FIle:

#header
{
background-image:url('texture.jpg');
height:10%;
font-variant:small-caps;
font-family:Lucida Console;
font-size: large;
line-height:480%;
margin:0;
padding:0;
}

#subheader
{
background-color:red;
font-family:Lucida Console;
width:100%;
height:4%;
margin:0;
padding:0;
text-align:right;
}

#sidebar
{
width:10%;
height:80%;
float:left;
background-color:yellow;
margin:0;
padding:0;
}


#content
{
background-color:green;
float:left;
width:90%;
height:80%;
margin:0;
padding:0;
}

#footer
{
background-color:blue;
margin:0;
padding:0;
}

h1
{
margin:0;
}

h3
{
margin:0;
}
```

Comment: try command+0 or CTRL+0 to reset browser scaling

Comment: nothing happening with that. Is there any issue with code?

Comment: Your css looks okay to me. From your question it sounds like you have browser scaling/zoom going on that is changing your window. Is the browser window the same size? Have you tried another browser?

Comment: Found it. The tag for h1 is missing > . Amazed how HTML works !!
Feeling silly now, couldn't spot this earlier. 
Thanks Willoller for your help. :)

Comment: Ha I missed that one too.  Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Found it. The tag for h1 is missing > . Amazed how HTML works !! Feeling silly now, couldn't spot this earlier. – TorontoSummers